# Is there a difference between doOnSuccess vs doOnNext for a Mono?

Tags: java, spring, java-8, spring-webflux, project-reactor

Let's say you have `Mono<Integer> someIntegerSource = Mono.just(5)` and you want to assign it to a variable.

Is there a difference between these code snippets?

**Case 1:** `doOnSuccess`

```
someIntegerSource.doOnSuccess(number -> this.myNumber = number)
```

**Case 2:** `doOnNext`

```
someIntegerSource.doOnNext(number -> this.myNumber = number)
```

**Case 3:** `doOnSuccess` + `then` (because I want to the assignment to be complete before emitting completion of the mono)

```
someIntegerSource.doOnSuccess(number -> this.myNumber = number).then()
```

Answer (score 67, accepted):

Read the documentation of the class [`Mono`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html) and see the diagrams. The differences are not as subtle as they appear:

- [`Mono::doOnNext`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnNext-java.util.function.Consumer-) triggers when the data **is emitted** successfully, which means the data is available and present.
- [`Mono::doOnSuccess`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnSuccess-java.util.function.Consumer-) triggers when the `Mono` **completes** successfully - result is either `T` or `null`, which means the processing itself successfully finished regardless the state of data and is executed although the data are not available or present but the pipeline itself succeed.
- [`Mono::then`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#then--) as the end of the methods chain returns `Mono<Void>` on complete and error signals.

  - Note here the payload is actively dropped, that's why there becomes `Mono<Void>` from `Mono<T>`. Note the two methods above don't throw the payload away.

Follow the illustrative examples below:

#### Non-empty Mono

A `Mono` that holds a value triggers `doOnNext` when the data is emitted successfully. This can be confusing to the `doOnSuccess`, but contrary to such trigger, `doOnNext` is triggered when **any** successful value is emitted including an empty `Mono`, which is still valid.

```
Mono.just("Hello World")
    .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("On next: " + i))
    .doOnSuccess(i -> System.out.println("On success: " + i))
    .doOnError(i -> System.out.println("On error: " + i))
    .block();
```

```
On next: Hello World
On success: Hello World
```

#### Empty Mono

Remember, although the `Mono` is empty (`Mono.empty()`), it is still a valid response that triggers `doOnSuccess`, however not `doOnNext`, An empty `Mono` can be understood as one with a valid response that doesn't represent the desired output that contains a useful value. It works on the same principle as `Optional.empty()`. The `Mono` is successful but has no real useful value that would trigger `doOnNext` as it doesn't emit any value at all.

```
Mono.empty()
    .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("On next: " + i))
    .doOnSuccess(i -> System.out.println("On success: " + i))
    .doOnError(i -> System.out.println("On error: " + i))
    .block();
```

```
Mono.just("Hello World")
    .mapNotNull(s -> null)
    .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("On next: " + i))
    .doOnSuccess(i -> System.out.println("On success: " + i))
    .doOnError(i -> System.out.println("On error: " + i))
    .block();
```

Both result in the same output:

```
On success: null
```

#### Erroneous Mono

For sake of completeness to put in contrast with an empty `Mono`, the erroneous doesn't trigger either `doOnNext` or `doOnSuccess` but does `doOnError` instead:

```
Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Something wrong"))
    .doOnNext(i -> System.out.println("On next: " + i))
    .doOnSuccess(i -> System.out.println("On success: " + i))
    .doOnError(i -> System.out.println("On error: " + i))
    .block();
```

```
On error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Something wrong
```

#### A side note about `then`

The method `Mono::then` with either no argument or its overridden variant accepting `Mono<V>` discards the former result and supplies a new `Mono<Void` or `Mono<V>` respectively.

```java
Mono.empty()
    .then()
    .doOnSuccess(i -> System.out.println("On success: " + i))
    .doOnError(i -> System.out.println("On error: " + i))
    .block();

Mono.empty()
    .then(Mono.just("Good bye"))
    .doOnSuccess(i -> System.out.println("On success: " + i))
    .doOnError(i -> System.out.println("On error: " + i))
    .block();

Mono.just("Hello World")
    .then(Mono.just("Good bye"))
    .doOnSuccess(i -> System.out.println("On success: " + i))
    .doOnError(i -> System.out.println("On error: " + i))
    .block();

Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Something wrong"))
    .then(Mono.just("Good bye"))
    .doOnSuccess(i -> System.out.println("On success: " + i))
    .doOnError(i -> System.out.println("On error: " + i))
    .block();

Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Something wrong"))
    .then(Mono.error(new RuntimeException("Something very wrong")))
    .doOnSuccess(i -> System.out.println("On success: " + i))
    .doOnError(i -> System.out.println("On error: " + i))
    .block();
```

```java
On success: null
On success: Good bye
On success: Good bye
On error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Something wrong
On error: java.lang.RuntimeException: Something wrong
```

Comment: This is one the best breakdowns describing these differences on the web.